# Thought experiment: can one tell if a train is moving at constant speed or at rest without looking out of the window?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, thought-experiment

If you are in an isolated box on a train (assume the train is moving on a frictionless platform) and you are given a clock, simple pendulum, measuring scale and weights of different masses, can you find out that the train is at rest or moving with a constant velocity in a straight line?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. In its current form, it seems as if you're asking for the answer to a homework question. Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what you're not understanding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_Concerning_the_Two_Chief_World_Systems

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The most fundamental laws of physics have no velocity dependence, which means there is no physics experiment you could perform inside the train to tell whether the train was at rest on the tracks or moving in a straight line, without peeking out the window when no one is watching.

Remember too that just because the train is stopped on the tracks does not mean it is not moving. The earth to which the train is connected is rotating on its axis and is in orbit around the sun and the galaxy we live in is itself in motion.